# (Solved) Placing table and figure after the reference section (open question)

Tags: tables, landscape, endfloat

I have a relatively open question. I submitted a paper and now got a feedback form t&f journal. I need to move the tables inside text to the end of paper after the reference section. How can I do that? Any command to force latex to move them? 
Thanks,

Updated:

I have figured out the figures by using the following command

```
\usepackage[nolists,tablesfirst]{endfloat}
```

And I moved a long table to the end by:

```
\usepackage{endfloat,longtable}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavour*{longtable}{table}
```

But, the rest of tables are still in the text and did not move. Also, the long table did not rotate :). It looks like `\endfloat` does not compatiable with`{landscape}`.

Any suggestion?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{epstopdf}% To incorporate .eps illustrations using PDFLaTeX, etc.
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}% Support for small, `sub' figures and tab
\usepackage[nolists,Figuresfirst]{endfloat}% To `separate' figures and tables from text if required

\usepackage{endfloat,longtable}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavour*{longtable}{table}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{landscape}{table}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
\newcommand{\heading}[1]{\bfseries\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} 
#1\end{tabular}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X} % 
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\frenchspacing
\makeatletter
\def\endthebibliography{%
\def\@noitemerr{\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
\endlist
}

  \makeatother
  \def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
  T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
 \begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{Our Dimensions}
\small % "\footnotesize" not necessarry
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ lL @{}}
     % rel. widths of columns 2 and 3 add up to "2".
   %  >{\hsize=0.55\hsize} }
\toprule
%\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & & \\
%& & &\\
Dimensions & Values  \\ \midrule
Paradigm & GT - Game theory
  \\ 
&C - Cognitive\\
\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\label{tab:ourdim}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the `endfloat` package?

Comment: I add this (\usepackage[nolists,tablesfirst]{endfloat}) to my text but only figure moved after the references. Tables are still in the text.

Comment: Please tell us how the tables are set up in the body of the document. E.g., do you actually use `table` environments? If so, do you maybe use the `[H]` placement specifier? Please advise.

Comment: I use tabularx and table environments. [H] does not work.

Comment: Please tell us which TeX distribution you employ -- and how old the TeX distribution is. When was it last updated?

Comment: Do note that, in my earlier comment, I was not suggesting that you use `[H]` placement specifiers. Instead, I was merely asking if you use them. I gather that the answer is "no".

Comment: @Mico Texmaker 4.5

Comment: TeXmaker is not a TeX distribution, it's merely a front-end to a TeX distribution. Which TeX distribution do you employ?

Comment: @Mico Tex Live, have not updated for a while. But, I do not think so it causes the problem. Becuase, with this command I able to move the long table to the end but \usepackage{endfloat,longtable}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavour*{longtable}{table}. But, the table does not rotate as I want (does not fit to the margin).

Comment: @AH2012 Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: @samcarter added.